# Unexpeced output of java 7 nio 2 program

Tags: java, nio2, watchservice

I am trying a small program from [Pro Java 7 NIO.2](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Pro_Java_7_NIO_2.html?id=_kvm1aJyph8C)
Page No 118

Code is :

```
class WatchRafaelNadal {
    public void watchRNDir(Path path) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try (WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
           path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);

                //start an infinite loop
                while (true) {
                //retrieve and remove the next watch key
                final WatchKey key = watchService.take();
                //get list of pending events for the watch key
                for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {

                //get the kind of event (create, modify, delete)
                final Kind<?> kind = watchEvent.kind();
                //handle OVERFLOW event
                if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
                }
                //get the filename for the event
                final WatchEvent<Path> watchEventPath = (WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent;
                final Path filename = watchEventPath.context();
                //print it out
                System.out.println(kind + " -> " + filename);
                }
                //reset the key
                boolean valid = key.reset();
                //exit loop if the key is not valid (if the directory was deleted, for example)
                if (!valid) {
                break;
                }
           }
       }
    }
}

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Path path = Paths.get("C:/Java");
            WatchRafaelNadal watch = new WatchRafaelNadal();
            try {
            watch.watchRNDir(path);
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
}
```

But when I changed a line in `global.properties` ( or any file ) present in folder `C:\\Java` I get output as -

```
 ENTRY_MODIFY  -> global.properties
 ENTRY_MODIFY  -> global.properties
```

Why it is raising event 2 times ?
Is there any service available in Java to detect exact modified line/lines in file ?

JDK : jdk1.7.0_09 
IDE : Eclipse Java EE IDE Version : Juno Release 
Platform : Windows 7

Comment: How did you change that line? An editor may easily make two separate OS-level modifications when you hit Save.

Comment: I tried with Notepad, Notepad++, MSOffice Word, WordPad but still same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you change the file?

Maybe you *technically* changed the file *twice*.

For example, first the contents are changed, then the file meta data are updated, that makes two events.

It's probably best if you implement your application in a way that it can handle such situations.